# elasticsearch string values vs ids- performance best practices

Tags: elasticsearch

i wonder whats better from performance aspect:
to store string values in elasticsearch, or to save a map table in mysql(for example), and save the id.
for example 10M documents with a field 'browser', with all browsers' names,
or with ids, that i pre-generated and saved in mysql

use case is analyze server traffic

thanks!

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with that data. Why do you want to store it in ES in the first place? Please explain your use case.

Comment: use case is analyze server traffic, search traffic, aggregate- for example by browser

Comment: Ok, but I don't quite get what benefit you expect to get from having mysql in the picture

Comment: im asking if elasticsaerch will perform better if i save in all the text fields an id instead of a string. for example: "browser":"1", instead of "browser":"chrome"

Comment: And how do you expect to search for `chrome` if you store an id instead of the text? ES is really meant for that kind of stuff. The best thing to do is to try for yourself and you'll quickly see.

Comment: im working with ElasticSearch for few years. i'm thinking if this is a possible optimization.

Comment: whether you filter on an id or on an exact value (keyword field) makes no big difference... so why would you bother having to make another lookup in mysql?